# PHP Combine arrays in a loop

Tags: php

Currently I want to output a data from a database. I have two separate arrays. May I know is there a way to combine those arrays. The code is as below,

```
$array_1 = [
  'memo' => 'title string',
  'break_down' => 'title string',
  'images' => 'title string',
  'email_content' => 'title string'
];

// content from db
$array_2 = [$memo, $break_down, $images, $email_content];


// I want it to display like this
<?php foreach ($array_1 as $key=> $name) : ?>

<p>
<?= $name; ?> = <?php  //content on $array_2 ?> 
<?php //eg: title string = $memo and so on.. ?>
</p>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$keys = array_keys($array_1);
$array_2 = array_combine($keys, $array_2);

foreach ($array_1 as $key => $name): ?>
<p>
<?= $name; ?> = <?php echo $array_2[$key]; ...
```

Note that you can also have the keys you want directly from your SQL query using the `as` SQL keyword:

```
select field1 as memo, field2 as break_down ...
```

and using [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) or [PDO::FETCH_ASSOC](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: Thank you for the help. If I use the sql query string, I do not need to assign the array like on $array_2 right?

Comment: @Amran: indeed, if you only want to display your query results and if you use `as` in your query (or if columns have already the good names), you don't need to use array_combine to *re*build a new array.